# PHP foreach not looping

Tags: php, foreach

I just built a simple foreach loop to run through an array, but nothing is displaying.
No php errors by the way.

**Can someone tell me why this isn't working?**

```
$test = array (
            "1" => array(
                "name"=>"something"
            ),
            "2" => array(
                "name"=>"something"
            )
        );

foreach ($test as $key => $arr) {
    echo $arr[$key]["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant...

```
foreach ($test as $key => $arr) {
    echo $test[$key]["name"];
}
```

Or, even more simply...

```
foreach ($test as $key => $arr) {
    echo $arr["name"];
}
```

Comment: `$arr` is just a convenient way to refer to `$test[$key]`.  See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I edited the post to use `$arr` instead.  You have a few ways to do this, obviously.

Comment: I'm about to hit myself for making it more complicated. I'm not a noob when it comes to php, but I'm never looping through my own arrays, just the ones I pull back from a database..

Answer (score 5):

Just use `$arr["name"]` instead of `$arr[$key]["name"]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($test as $key => $arr) {
    echo $test[$key]["name"];
}
```

OR

```
foreach ($test as $key => $arr) {
    echo $arr["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is written in a way that "1" and "2" are values and not keys.

what you need is:

```
$test = array (
        array(
            "name"=>"something"
        ),
        array(
            "name"=>"something"
        )
    );
```

also, you have a typo on your foreach. you need `$test[$key]` and not `$arr[$key]`

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh... (slams head down on desk)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the $key key in the array reference.

```
foreach ($test as $arr) {
   echo $arr["name"];
}
```

You can address the field of the array like

```
foreach ($test as $key=>$arr) {
    $test[$key][$name]
}
```

but doing so you do not use the direct reference to the inner arrays

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach ($test as $key => $arr) {
    echo $arr["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo $arr["name"];
```

or

```
echo $test[$key]["name"];
```